# How to process the results from node-zillow?

Tags: node.js, zillow

zillow package for a project. I've successfully executed a GetSearchResults() and gotten a response, but I don't exactly know how to process the response to get the information from it. For example, here is the log in the terminal from the call:

```
{ request:
   { address: '113 Cherry St',
     citystatezip: 'Seattle, Washington' },
  message: { text: 'Request successfully processed', code: '0' },
  response: { results: { result: [Array] } } }
```

I see that I have an array called result which I presume has the information in it but how do I go about processing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using the [`node-zillow`](https://github.com/ralucas/node-zillow) package. I signed up for a zillow api key to play with the package. Hard to believe the official API only returns XML...

To navigate the resulting JSON and print out the first `results`, first set of `links`, and grab its first `homedetails` url.

```
const Zillow = require('node-zillow');

// get key from environment variable
const z = new Zillow(process.env.ZWSID);

const params = {
  address: '2512 Mapleton Ave.',
  citystatezip: '80304',
};

// store the results
const results = await z.get('GetSearchResults', params);

const homeDetails = results.response.results.result[0].links[0].homedetails[0];

console.log(homeDetails);
```

which prints out

```
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2512-...
```

Comment: So if I want to set a variable equal to something like the address in the first row for example, do I do something like var homedetails=results.response.results.result[0].address[0];? I know this isnt correct but is this about the right idea?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. It would be better to `await` the results if you're working synchronously so I updated the above answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation looks like you're dealing with promises. So I recommend  simply doing this:

```
 GetSearchResults() 
 .then(function(results) {
    //handle your results here for instance
    console.log(results) 
  })
```